# Python loop restarting even though there is a try: except:

Tags: python, loops, except

Here is the code for a small program I just wrote to test some new things I learned.

```
while 1:
    try:
        a = input("How old are you? ")
    except:
        print "Your answer must be a number!"
        continue

    years_100 = 100 - a
    years_100 = str(years_100)
    a = str(a)
    print "You said you were "+a+", so that means you still have "+years_100+" years"
    print "to go until you are 100!"
    break
while 2:
    try:
        b = str(raw_input('Do you want to do it again? If yes enter "yes", otherwise type "no" to stop the script.'))
    except:
        print 'Please try again. Enter "yes" to do it again, or "no" to stop.'
        continue

    if b == "yes":
            print 'You entered "yes". Script will now restart... '
    elif b == "no":
            print 'You entered "no". Script will now stop.' 
            break
```

It works fine for the for loop. If you type something other than a number, it will tell you only numbers are allowed.

However, in the 2nd loop, it asks you to enter yes or no, but if you enter in something different, it just restarts the loop instead of printing the message after

```
except:
```

What did I do wrong and how do I fix it so it displays the message I told it to?

Comment: Please don't blindly catch any exception - it is really bad practice as it makes it very hard to spot errors - instead, catch the exact exception that you are managing. It's also worth noting that `while 1:` is better put as `while True` - you should also move the stuff you don't wish to be repeated outside of the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not get an exception, because you are *always* enter a string when using `raw_input()`. Thus `str()` on the return value of `raw_input()` will never fail.

Instead, add an `else` statement to your `yes` or `no` tests:

```
if b == "yes":
        print 'You entered "yes". Script will now restart... '
elif b == "no":
        print 'You entered "no". Script will now stop.' 
        break
else:
    print 'Please try again. Enter "yes" to do it again, or "no" to stop.'
    continue
```

Note that you should never use a blanket `except` statement; catch *specific* exceptions. Otherwise, you'll mask unrelated problems, making it harder for you to find those problems.

Your first except handler should only catch `NameError`, `EOFError` and `SyntaxError` for example:

```
try:
    a = input("How old are you? ")
except (NameError, SyntaxError, EOFError):
    print "Your answer must be a number!"
    continue
```

as that's what `input()` would throw.

Also note that `input()` takes *any* python expression. If I enter `"Hello program"` (with the quotes), no exception would be raised, but it is not a number either. Use `int(raw_input())` instead, and then catch `ValueError` (what would be thrown if you entered anything that's not an integer) and `EOFError` for `raw_input`:

```
try:
    a = int(raw_input("How old are you? "))
except (ValueError, EOFError):
    print "Your answer must be a number!"
    continue
```

To use the second loop to control the first, make it a function that returns `True` or `False`:

```
def yes_or_no():
    while True:
        try:
            cont = raw_input('Do you want to do it again? If yes enter "yes", otherwise type "no" to stop the script.'))
        except EOFError:
            cont = ''  # not yes and not no, so it'll loop again.
        cont = cont.strip().lower()  # remove whitespace and make it lowercase
        if cont == 'yes':
            print 'You entered "yes". Script will now restart... '
            return True
        if cont == 'no':
            print 'You entered "no". Script will now stop.' 
            return False
        print 'Please try again. Enter "yes" to do it again, or "no" to stop.'
```

and in the other loop:

```
while True:
    # ask for a number, etc.

    if not yes_or_no():
        break  # False was returned from yes_or_no
    # True was returned, we continue the loop
```

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for helping!  Also, is there a way to return back to the first loop?

Comment: You'll have to *nest* the loops, or use a function perhaps (return `True` when `yes` was entered, or `False` for `no`, then use that return value to break or continue.

Comment: Can you use that to return 1 if there is a loop while 1:?

Comment: Use it instead of the `break` at the end of the first `while` loop. Create a function that asks the user for `yes` or `no` (in a loop as you have it now), and use the return value.

Comment: raw_input() might raise EOFError

Comment: sometimes an empty string might be returned instead of EOFError depending on OS, whether readline is used, etc.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: In any case, catching it won't hurt. Catching it to assign the empty string to `cont`..

Comment: I'm not sure that you can ignore EOFError i.e., once you've encountered it, stdin might not be usable.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I am able to cause a EOF by entering a `^D` (Control-D) in a bash terminal, and stdin is still fine.

Comment: `echo abc | python your_script.py` leads to infinite loop. `^D`, `^Z` (Win) behavior (whether stdin is usable) might vary.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I'd say that for a learning-python-still question like this we don't need to guard for pipe usage..